# Escribir un texto automaticamente en excel dependiendo de otra casilla con caracteres especiales

Tags: excel

Buenas me encuentro con un error al intentar que en Excel, una casilla en blanco mediante una formula, escriba automaticamente un texto en la otra tabla dependiendo del valor que tenga otra casilla.
Me refiero yo tengo La columna TYPE_NAME, y TYPE.
En TYPE, puedo tener 3 valores:

- FI.
- FI
- FF

Dependiendo de lo que haya en esa casilla, yo quiero escribir Boolean, Word o Float(RESPECTIVAMENTE)

He intentado con varias opciones como puede ser esto:

> =SI(ESNUMERO(ENCONTRAR("FF";H2));"Float";SI(ESNUMERO(ENCONTRAR("FI";H2));"Word";SI(ESNUMERO(ENCONTRAR("FI.";$H2));"Boolean";"")))

Pero no consigo hacer que funcione correctamente.
El FI. no lo recoge y no logra diferenciarlo del FI normal.
He probado poniendo en ingles, con hallar y otras funciones pero no lo más cerca que he estado ha sido esto

Comment: Cambia el orden de los argumentos. Piensa que dentro de `FI.` existe la cadena `FI` por lo que Excel nunca a llega a leer el último ENCONTRAR. En cualquier caso creo que con solo SIES anidados podrías hacerlo, no entiendo el por qué usar ESNUMERO o ENCONTRAR

Comment: muchas graciias, con el cambio de fi. por el fi ha funcionado, pero lo que no entiendo es con el SIES, como deberia escribir la sentencia ?

Comment: Me refiero a algo tipo `=SI(A1="FI.";"Boolean";SI(A1="FI";"Word";"Float"))`